# how to parse the json below into string

Tags: java, android

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Instant Coffee",
    "price": 28.53,
    "on_hand_quantity": 27
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Cranberries - Dry",
    "price": 30.02,
    "on_hand_quantity": 29
  }
]
```

Comment: attach the netwrok client that you want to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse json in Android easily

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray (result);
for(int i=0; I<jArray.length; i++){
   JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

   String name = jObject.getString("name");
}
```

Comment: that really solved my issue.